# Why does iconv exit with error when reading from SVN transaction and not from SVN revision?

Tags: linux, svn, bash, pre-commit-hook

%% **Problem solved and the code below acts as expected** %%

I'm trying to write a SVN pre-commit hook in Bash that tests incoming files for UTF-8 encoding. After a lot of string juggling to get the path of the incoming files and ignore dirs/pictures/deleted files and so on, I use 'svnlook cat' to read the incoming file and pipe it to 'iconv -f UTF-8'. After this I read the exit status of the iconv operation with ${PIPESTATUS[1]}.

My code look like this:

```
REPOS="$1"
TXN="$2"

SVNLOOK=/usr/bin/svnlook
ICONV=/usr/bin/iconv

# The file endings to ignore when checking for UTF-8:
IGNORED_ENDINGS=( png jar )

# Prepairing to set the IFS (Internal Field Separator) so "for CHANGE in ..." will iterate
# over lines instead of words
OIFS="${IFS}"
NIFS=$'\n'

# Make sure that all files to be committed are encoded in UTF-8
IFS="${NIFS}"

for CHANGE in $($SVNLOOK changed -t "$TXN" "$REPOS"); do
    IFS="${OIFS}"
    # Skip change if first character is "D" (we dont care about checking deleted files)
    if [ "${CHANGE:0:1}" == "D" ]; then
        continue
    fi

    # Skip change if it is a directory (directories don't have encoding)
    if [ "${CHANGE:(-1)}" == "/" ]; then
        continue
    fi

    # Extract file repository path (remove first 4 characters)
    FILEPATH=${CHANGE:4:(${#CHANGE}-4)}

    # Ignore files that starts with "." like ".classpath"
    IFS="//" # Change seperator to "/" so we can find the file in the file path
    for SPLIT in $FILEPATH
    do
        FILE=$SPLIT
    done
    if [ "${FILE:0:1}" == "." ]; then
        continue
    fi
    IFS="${OIFS}" # Reset Internal Field Seperator

    # Ignore files that are not supposed to be checked, like images. (list defined in IGNORED_ENDINGS field above)
    IFS="." # Change seperator to "." so we can find the file ending
    for SPLIT in $FILE
    do
        ENDING=$SPLIT
    done
    IFS="${OIFS}" # Reset Internal Field Seperator
    IGNORE="0"
    for IGNORED_ENDING in ${IGNORED_ENDINGS[@]}
    do
        if [ `echo $IGNORED_ENDING | tr [:upper:] [:lower:]` == `echo $ENDING | tr [:upper:] [:lower:]` ] # case insensitive compare of strings
        then
            IGNORE="1"
        fi
    done
    if [ "$IGNORE" == "1" ]; then
        continue
    fi

    # Read changed file and pipe it to iconv to parse it as UTF-8
    $SVNLOOK cat -t "$TXN" "$REPOS" "$FILEPATH" | $ICONV -f UTF-8 -t UTF-16 -o /dev/null

    # If iconv exited with a non-zero value (error) then return error text and reject commit
    if [ "${PIPESTATUS[1]}" != "0" ]; then
        echo "Only UTF-8 files can be committed (violated in $FILEPATH)" 1>&2
        exit 1
    fi
    IFS="${NIFS}"
done

IFS="${OIFS}"

# All checks passed, so allow the commit.
exit 0
```

The problem is, every time I try to commit a file with Scandinavian characters like "æøå" iconv returns an error (exit 1).

If I disable the script, commit the file with "æøå", change the -t (transaction) in "svnlook -t" and "svnlook cat -t" to a -r (revision), and run the script manually with the revision number of the "æøå" file, then iconv (and therefor the script) returns exit 0. And everthing is dandy.

Why does svnlook cat -r work as expected (returning UTF-8 encoded "æøå" string), but not svnlook cat -t?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that iconv apparently behaves unexpectedly if no output encoding is selected.

Changing

```
$SVNLOOK cat -t "$TXN" "$REPOS" "$FILEPATH" | $ICONV -f UTF-8 -o /dev/null
```

to

```
$SVNLOOK cat -t "$TXN" "$REPOS" "$FILEPATH" | $ICONV -f UTF-8 -t UTF-16 -o /dev/null
```

solved the problem, and made the script behave as expected :)